# How to visualize overlapping intervals?

Tags: data-visualization

I have an interval, say (1 to 100). Then I have many little subintervals:

- (3,6)
- (5,15)
- (4,78)
- ...

I want to plot and visualise them. I'm interested in how they overlap each other.

**Q:** What is the most appropriate data visualization tool for doing that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21506875/1627235)?

Comment: This is not really a statistical question. You might get better answers at [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Computer Graphics.SE](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) or [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @StephanKolassa I **don't** realy thing that the sites are relevant for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach is to plot it as lines with whiskers, like on the example below (I'm using here ggplot2 with `geom_errorbar` as [described in here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/)).

[image]